# Facebook like button doesn't work with Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I cannot like facebook pages via facebook like button on my website. I can do it on Facebook but not my site.

Are there any known reason for this behavior?

I'm trying it on different sites and facebook pages, different states of facebook application (developer/live).

Comment: Are you within the European region? There are several restrictions that apply to the use of their social plugins there, you find them listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/